# specific .NET network library

Tags: .net, networking

I have a .NET server application which receive runtime data from somewhere(about 10 small packages, less then 100 bytes, per second). This application should pass this data to connected clients asap. The only way I see is to call client's callbacks immidiatly after receiving data. I tried WCF, but overhead kill performance.
So I need a .NET network library which can
 - work over tcp
 - proceed callbacks
 - handle large number of connections(about 1000 clients)
 - work throw proxies, without additional opened ports 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for "C# Network Library"?  There are numerous search results that might qualify.

Comment: No one from top 2 google pages did not supported callbacks throw proxies.

Comment: what overhead are you referring to with WCF? It can work over tcp too you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.aspx), but I strongly encourage you to pinpoint the performance problem with WCF...you should be able to deactivate behaviors or other overhead that is killing your performance. You're going to have a long road in replicating all that stuff you get for free with WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
Write your network code in C and call it from your C#